# Report Bucket Field: How can I display the latest data (child of Acc) on the report and hide the others that are older?

Tags: reporting, bucket

How can I display the latest data (child of Acc) on the report and hide the others that are older? How can i handle that directly on a report?

Is there a way to created a bucket field to say: Show me only the oldest records of a child from an Account?!

Thank you